# Why myVar = strings.Fields(scanner.Text()) take much more time than comparable operation in python?

Tags: python, go

Consider the following code in golang

```
now := time.Now()
sec1 := now.Unix()

file, err := os.Open(file_name)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer file.Close()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

var parsedLine []string

for scanner.Scan() {
    parsedLine = strings.Fields(scanner.Text())
}

fmt.Println(parsedLine)
now2 := time.Now()
sec2 := now2.Unix()
fmt.Println(sec2 - sec1) // takes 24 second for file1.txt
```

And consider this python program

```
start = time.time()

with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        parsedLine = line.split()

end = time.time() 
print end - start # takes 4.6450419426 second for file1.txt
```

I observe the golang program is 5 times slower than the python program on a mac book pro

Specifically this line

```
parsedLine = strings.Fields(scanner.Text())
```

is very slow.

If I change that line in golang to

```
if strings.Contains(scanner.Text(), "string_that_never_exist") {
     continue
}
// take less than 1 second
```

and python to

```
if "string_that_never_exist" in line:
    continue
# takes 2.86928987503 second
```

Golang version is now much faster than python one.

I am slightly perplexed on why `strings.Fields(scanner.Text())` may be slower than `line.split()`

I feel I am missing something silly, can someone point me out why the golang version take longer than python

Comment: The functions do different things, did you try with `strings.Split`?

Comment: Interesting, ```strings.Split(scanner.Text(), " ")```  speed is slightly faster to python, but I think it doesn't split by multiple space as python does,  [go playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/cNPgsp_Vcin)

Comment: You can either have the more complete behavior of `strings.Fields`, the basic `strings.Split` implementation, or implement your own python-equivalent split.

Answer (score 3):

Any benchmark should be a good scientific experiment. It must be reproducible.

First, define the readily available input:

The Complete Works of William Shakespeare by William Shakespeare:

`http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt`

Next, fully define the executable programs:

`linesplit.py`:

```
import time; 
start = time.time()

# http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt
file = "/home/peter/shakespeare.100-0.txt"
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        parsedLine = line.split()

end = time.time() 
print (end - start)
```

`linesplit.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    sec1 := now.Unix()

    // http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt
    file_name := "/home/peter/shakespeare.100-0.txt"
    file, err := os.Open(file_name)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    var parsedLine []string

    for scanner.Scan() {
        parsedLine = strings.Fields(scanner.Text())
    }

    fmt.Println(parsedLine)
    now2 := time.Now()
    sec2 := now2.Unix()
    fmt.Println(sec2 - sec1) // takes 24 second for file1.txt
    fmt.Println(time.Since(now))
}
```

Then, provide the benchmark results:

```
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.14
$ time python2 linesplit.py
.07024809169769
real    0m0.089s
user    0m0.089s
sys     0m0.000s

$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.3
$ time python3 linesplit.py
0.12172794342041016
real    0m0.159s
user    0m0.155s
sys     0m0.004s

$ go version
go version devel +39ad208c13 Tue Jun 12 19:10:34 2018 +0000 linux/amd64
$ go build linesplit.go && time ./linesplit
[]
1
91.833622ms
real    0m0.100s
user    0m0.094s
sys     0m0.004s

$
```

We have Python2 < Go < Python3 or 0.0724 < 0.0918 < 0.1217 or, as a ratio, 1.00 < 1.31 < 1.73. Python2 is ASCII. Go and Python3 are Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

You're using Unicode in Go and bytestrings in Python. Your Python code has a much easier job, since it doesn't have to do Unicode decoding or handle all Unicode whitespace values.

Comment: Interesting, is there out of box utility that does what python `line.split()` does but faster in golang?

Comment: actually, I think python takes care of unicode too ```a = u'a\tb' ``` ```a.split()``` gives ```[u'a', u'b']``` , or maybe I am confused on what unicode means

Comment: @Jal: Python supports Unicode, but you're not using it.

Comment: so does that mean ```for line in f:``` auto covert content of line from unicode to string? and why does ```fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(scanner.Text()))``` return ```string``` instead of unicode type

Comment: @Jal: there is no "unicode type" string in GO. Strings are a series of runes, though  they can be indexed as bytes.

Comment: I see, although I am still not sure why go is slower than python when python takes care of unicode also eg. ```a = u'a\tb' a.split() gives [u'a', u'b']``` , looks like I have to read more on what unicode decoding means