# How to improve file encoding conversion in Go

Tags: python, go, encoding, io, character-encoding

I've been working with some huge files that I have to convert to UTF-8, as the files ar enormous traditional tools like iconv won't work. So I decided to write my own tool in Go, however I noticed that this encoding conversion is quite slow in Go. here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 3 {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "usage:\n\t%s [input] [output]\n", os.Args[0])
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    f, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    out, err := os.Create(os.Args[2])

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    r := charmap.ISO8859_1.NewDecoder().Reader(f)

    buf := make([]byte, 1048576)

    io.CopyBuffer(out, r, buf)

    out.Close()
    f.Close()
}
```

Similar code in Python is much more performant:

```
import codecs
BLOCKSIZE = 1048576 # or some other, desired size in bytes
with codecs.open("FRWAC-01.xml", "r", "latin_1") as sourceFile:
    with codecs.open("FRWAC-01-utf8.xml", "w", "utf-8") as targetFile:
        while True:
            contents = sourceFile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not contents:
                break
            targetFile.write(contents)
```

I was sure my Go code would be much quicker because in general I/O in Go is fast, but it turns out is much slower than the Python code. Is there a way to improve the Go program?

Comment: You might be able to get slightly better performance wrapping the files with `bufio` and adjusting the copy buffer size, but the Go version should be pretty fast. Please provide a [mcve], because on my system the python example is 30x slower

Comment: Here is an example of how to construct a performance benchmark: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50825059/221700

Comment: Had a moment to try and look at this. My original test inadvertently used python2, which turns out to be much slower. With python3 the times seem comparable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not comparing the same code in both cases. Also IO speed in Go can't be significantly different that python, since they are making the same syscalls.

In the python version, the files are buffered by default. In the Go version, while you're using `io.CopyBuffer` with a `1048576` byte buffer, the decoder is going to make whatever size `Read` calls it needs directly on the unbuffered file.

Wrapping the file IO with `bufio` will produce comparable results.

```
inFile, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer inFile.Close()

outFile, err := os.Create(os.Args[2])
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer outFile.Close()

in := bufio.NewReaderSize(inFile, 1<<20)

out := bufio.NewWriterSize(outFile, 1<<20)
defer out.Flush()

r := charmap.ISO8859_1.NewDecoder().Reader(in)

if _, err := io.Copy(out, r); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: This improved a lot the performance but still the difference is huge. I am working with 2Gb to 30Gb files and the problem is that they are not public, I'll create some dummy files for having a reproducible example. For now, with your change, for a 1.8Gb file I have: `time python testpy.py

real    0m5.313s
user    0m2.225s
sys     0m2.584s`  and `time ./testgo FRWAC-01.xml FRWAC-01-utf8.xml

real    0m9.220s
user    0m4.929s
sys     0m2.340s`

Comment: On further testing, adding the buffers did make a difference (adding another buffer in the copy step also helps). Results are now comparable, however after doing some tests with pprof I am under the impression that go's `text/encoding/charmap` library is a bit slower than python's `codecs`.